# Ubuntu Server stuck at boot (Starting uuid generator uuid)

Tags: boot, server

When I originally installed a brand new server using netinstall and booted a freshly new installed Ubuntu, it wouldn't boot, but I resolved that with the `vga=normal nomodeset` kernel parameters.

Now it is stuck at `Starting uuid generator uuid`

The server will only boot well whenever I boot the recovery mode and resume.

Here are the logs os the server:

- [kern.log](http://pastebin.com/R1YiwpYq)
- [dmesg](http://pastebin.com/1PMrDb4V)
- [Syslog](http://pastebin.com/DSPcSeRX)

The NV card is an onboard one, there are no additional USB ports in use and WiFi isn't on there either. It is an 14.10 server image, and yes, I am familiar with Ubuntu servers. And for some reason I cannot turn off the power management. It is permanently grayed out, whatever I do. The motherboard is an Asus M2NBP-VM CSM and the BIOS has been updated to the Revision 1001 standard.

Apparently I have fixed it, I again tried *nomodeset*, but without any other option. And although I've tried without *splash quiet*, it appears my system is in conflict with *$vt_handoff*. I'm also referencing to a [blog](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-fix-ubuntu-boot-splash-screen-after-grub-updates) whom has experienced a similar problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Has this ever worked? Could you boot with a LiveCD and post the `/var/log/kern.log` `dmesg` and `syslog` that have a size larger then 1K to http://paste.ubuntu.com ? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Here's the syslog: http://pastebin.com/DSPcSeRX

Comment: As your reputation is too low, I cannot take this up in chat, so: Can you yank out the NVidia card?  Actually: get rid of everything you don't need (disable in BIOS or remove) USB ports, parallel ports, WiFi, ... Are you using a server image? Are you familiar with Ubuntu servers?  How many years?

Comment: Did you disable power management? What version are you running? 14.10? What's the brand/model? Did you upgrade the BIOS? Please [edit] your question to give a chronological order in which you did things...